# Postfix, ruled based filtering independently for each user

Tags: postfix, sendmail, filtering

I managed to create successfully a white-list sender email filter see: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613639/filering-received-mail-by-aliases-file-ubuntu-postfix-mail-server).

My goal now is to have separate filter for each user. I would like to filter out all the emails based on the rules created send to the group email `all@mydomain.com`, but I do not wish to limit the personal emails to `user{(1-9)*}@mydomain.com`. The aliases file is setup as `all: user1, user2, user3 ...`.

Is this user based mail filtering possible or should I try something more complex such as triggering a `php script` on email reception see: [here](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail)?

Update:

In the end, as there was no better way I followed the example [here](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/IntegratedSpamdInPostfix) (and [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/add-disclaimers-to-outgoing-emails-with-altermime-postfix-debian-etch)), where I modified the bash file to execute my own filters. Still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can use `procmail`, or `maildrop`

Comment: Thank you, I will check `maildrop`. `procmail` is no longer supported according to Wikipedia, so I will refrain from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a example for maildrop:

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
import EXT
import HOST
VPOP="| /home/vpopmail/bin/vdelivermail '' delete"
VHOME=`/home/vpopmail/bin/vuserinfo -d $EXT@$HOST`

DUMMY=`test -d $VHOME/Maildir`
if ( $RETURNCODE == 1 )
{
   echo "Sorry, no mailbox here by that name. (#5.1.1)"
   EXITCODE=100
   exit
}

DUMMY=`test -d $VHOME/Maildir/.Spam`
if ( $RETURNCODE == 1 )
{
   DUMMY=`/usr/bin/maildirmake -f Spam $VHOME/Maildir`
#   DUMMY=`echo Inbox.Spam >> $VHOME/Maildir/courierimapsubscribed`
}

#if ( $SIZE < 4621440 )
#{
#xfilter "/usr/local/bin/spamc -f -u nobody"
#}

if (/^X-Barracuda*/)
{
        echo "60.11 Message delivered to home dir"
        to "$VPOP"
        exit
}
else
{
        to "$VHOME/Maildir/.Spam"
        echo "Message delivered to $VHOME/Maildir/.Spam"
        exit
}
```